# Using hashmap as a database in Java Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller, thymeleaf

Im trying to create a login in Java, SpringBoot, and HTML (thymeleaf) but using a hashmap to store the username and password instead of SQL or the built in support. Im having trouble with it because it prints the hashmap on the website (im also trying to show those 2 values on the website), but it does it empty like this: " {} "
Here's what I've done:

Setters and getters:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Greeting {
   // id = username. content = password.
    private String id;
    private String content;
public Map<String, String> userAndPassword = new HashMap<>();

public void setId(String id) {
    // username
    this.id = id;
}

public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setContent(String content) {
    this.content = content;
}

public String getContent() {
    return content;
}

public void setuserAndPassword(Map<String,String> userAndPassword) {
    this.userAndPassword = userAndPassword;
    // adding username and password into the hashmap
    userAndPassword.put(id, content);
}

public Map<String, String> getuserAndPassword() {
    return userAndPassword;
}
}
```

The view (result.html):

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <title>Web Login</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Datos</h1>
    <p th:text="'User ID: ' + ${greeting.id}" />
    <p th:text="'Password: ' + ${greeting.content}" />
    <p th:text="'Printing out hashmap with all data: ' + ${greeting.userAndPassword}" />
</body>
</html>
```

Controller:

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;

@Controller
public class GreetingController {

    @GetMapping("/greeting")
    public String greetingForm(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("greeting", new Greeting());
        return "greeting";
    }

    @PostMapping("/greeting")
    public String greetingSubmit(@ModelAttribute Greeting greeting) {
        return "result";
    }

}
```

Comment: What about the controller code?

Comment: @Kayaman Just added

Comment: `Greeting` class does not follow to good practices (like proper encapsulation for example) and I do no understand the intent of its methods or how it is supposed to be used. Where and how do you initialize it? What is the purpose of the `userAndPassword` map in it?

Comment: @MartinBG this is the whole app, I havent left out any code. the userAndPassword map is a hashmap in which I am storing the id (username) and the content (password)

Comment: `new Greeting()` creates instance with default (`null`) `id` and `content` and empty `userAndPassword` map. That explains why these are empty in browser.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not fully clear to me. Assuming from your code after `post` call you want to land in `result` page. But you don't binding any `Greeting` object there. So try like bellow.

```
 @PostMapping("/greeting")
    public ModelAndView greetingSubmit(@ModelAttribute Greeting greeting) {
     ModelAndView mv= new ModelAndView("result");
      mv.addAddObject("greeting", greeting);
        return mv;
    }
```

hope that your `greeting` is not `null`